# JavaScript prototype vs. this in practice

Tags: javascript, oop

I've read many questions with valid and understandable answers here in Stack Overflow and other sites over the web, and I think I understand everything I need for using JavaScript to make object-oriented apps, save one thing: What is the real, practical purpose of using a class' `prototype` over `this`?

- I've read that any method, even one set as a `this` member, will be called from the constructor (class) function, and not re-created for each instance.
- I've seen many examples of using `prototype` for setting methods, implying that it would save memory by using the original class-function's method on the instance, and not a brand new attribute.

So, along with remarking which of the two options above is true, I'd like to know: is a `prototype` method accessing the constructor's `this` ("public") variables or the instance's (which may have been set as different from the constructor's)?

Edit - is using `this.prototype.method = function()` inside the constructor's scope wrong? All examples I've seen set a prototype method *after* the function has been created.

Comment: `this` is ref to `object`, `object` does not have property `prototype`

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't say there was an `object.this` property anywhere in the post.

Comment: when you use `this` inside constructors function - `this` is reference to created object

Comment: *"is using this.prototype.method = function() inside the constructor's scope wrong?"* Yes, almost certainly. The object `this` refers to almost certainly doesn't have a `prototype` property.

Comment: @Grundy: Exactly - what I mean is just `var A = function() { this.b = function() { return 1 } }` makes `A.b` accessible from outside, while `var A = function() { var b = function() { return 1 } }` makes it accessible only from inner methods. And the question is whether `var C = new A()`'s `C.b` is a new method or a reference to `A.b`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't all JavaScript functions have a prototype?

Comment: @gchiconi: Mostly (the ones returned by `Function#bind` don't), but that's not the point. The point is that `this` within the constructor function is **not** the constructor function, it's the object (which is not a function) created by the `new` operator.

Comment: Also, there's also a difference between an objects internal prototype and a constructors public prototype. this.prototype inside a constructor function doesn't make any sense because the new object doesn't have a public prototype.

Comment: @gchiconi so when `this.b = function() { return 1 } ` then you created new function on created object, when you add function in prototype then created object use ref to it

Comment: Right, I guess I get it now. The function that sets the object *is not* the object itself, and `object.constructor` finally makes sense.

Comment: using prototype is a lot faster: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-this-for-methods this may be neglectable in many cases, but if you want to create many instances of complex objects it might become crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question regarding the relationship between the prototype method and `this` by example.

From the [moz docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> If the method is on an object's prototype chain, **this** refers to the
>   object the method was called on, *as if the method was on the object*.

**Example:**

```
// Our constructor function
function Example() {
    this.publicGreet = "Hello World";
};

// Here the function is set as a property of the constructors prototype
Example.prototype.greet = function() {
    alert(this.publicGreet);
};

// This creates a new object and invokes the constructor function
// Sets publicGreet as a property of that object and assigns it the value "Hello World"
var exampleInstance = new Example();

// Looks up the prototype chain and invokes it as a method of exampleInstance
// Remember our definition of `this` for methods on the prototype chain?
// Hence, `this` refers to exampleInstance, therefore `this.publicGreet` is "Hello World"
exampleInstance.greet();
```

Answer (score 1):

This test should explain the performance problem: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-instance-functions/6

But yes, prototype saves memory because one callback is defined and instances simply points to this callback. There's no need to declare bunch of copies of the same callback.

Access issue: "this" declared within function inside this.prototype refers to "this" of instance: http://jsfiddle.net/pHtjK/

```
var b = Function;
b.prototype.a = function(){alert(this.b);};

var xyz = new b();
b.b = 'what';

b.a();
```